# convert from sqlite3 to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sqlite, osx-mavericks

I am trying to convert my rails app which i built with sqlite3 but in order to use heroku, i need to use postgresql.  I have tried every suggestion i found online and here on stackoverflow without any luck.  can you please help me?

this is my current database.yml:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

my current gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'paperclip'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

my gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (4.0.5)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.7)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    globalid (0.3.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.2.13)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    loofah (2.0.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.6.0)
    multi_json (1.11.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    rack (1.6.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    sass (3.4.13)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sequel (3.20.0)
    simple_form (3.1.0)
      actionpack (~> 4.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    spring (1.3.4)
    sprockets (3.0.1)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10)
    taps (0.3.24)
      rack (>= 1.0.1)
      rest-client (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7.0)
      sequel (~> 3.20.0)
      sinatra (~> 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.1.2)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  paperclip
  rails (= 4.2.1)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  simple_form
  spring
  sqlite3
  taps (~> 0.3.22)
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

Now getting this error:

```
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_efbe3fb311a683f3c20ccebf588383f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_efbe3fb311a683f3c20ccebf588383f4/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.10), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.10'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include the PostgresQL gem to your Gemfile

`gem 'pg'`

I also recommend using the Rails 12 factor app gem. It basically precompiles your assets and gets everything ready for heroku automatically when your app is used in a production environment:

`gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

Change the production part of your database config to:

`production:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

I recently [wrote a short blog on how to start using Rails with Heroku](http://jnthn.info/2015/04/01/basics-of-deployment-with-heroku.html) for some more information if it helps. Here's a [quick link to a great guide by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction) if you haven't seen it already too.

As you're now using Postresql in your production environment and because Heroku doesn't support sqlite. You must change your Gemfile to only install sqlite for your development and test environments (unless you want them to use postgres too).

`group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end`

Comment: i did that already with this tutorial: http://blog.scottlesser.com/post/22307547950/switching-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-rails and still getting an error

Comment: The error message says that Heroku cant install the 'sqlite3' gem. This is because its currently listed in your Gemfile for all environments.

Change your Gemfile so that `gem 'sqlite3'` is only installed for development and test environments.

Comment: Change the line:

`gem 'sqlite3'` in your gem file

to this:

```group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end```

Comment: between? sorry just getting frustrated haha

Comment: ok, i got it all uploaded now but now i cant access the site haha. https://gigitt.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Great, sorry I'm unable to help with the new problems. Will need more information but glad your initial issue is sorted.

Comment: Actually I am now up and running. Realized that I didn't run migrate for heroku haha